# Symmetric group and commuting elements

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

What is the normalizer of the subgroup $\langle(1,2,...,p)\rangle$ in $S_p$? Clearly it will have to contain the subgroup $\langle(1,2,...,p)\rangle$, but also some additional $p-1$ elements that commute with the elements within $\langle(1,2,...,p)\rangle$. But what are they?

**EDIT:** Sorry, I have misread the question, it should be the subgroup $\langle(1,2,...,p)\rangle$ in the ***permutation group*** $S_p$, which I believe has order $p!$?

Comment: Isn'it normal since it's index two?

Comment: Reflections. [See wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) The rotations are a subgroup of index 2, hence normal, so every other symmetry of the p-gon wil normalize it, in particular the reflections and the unity.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Thanks, sorry, my mistake, I misunderstood $S_p$ to be the symmetric group of a p-gon (which should be $D_{2\times p}$, right?) I just mean the cyclic group $\langle(1,2,...,p)\rangle$ in the symmetric group $S_p$.

Comment: @Myself: Thanks, sorry for my mistake, but I meant $S_p$. Please c.f. my comment to Alex.

Comment: Okay, here's a 'hint': try to determine an element that maps $x = (1,2,\dots,p)$ to $x^2 = (1,3,\dots,p,2,\dots,p-1)$. Because $x^2$ generates that subgroup, such an element will normalize the group. (And similarly for $x^3$, ...)

Comment: (By the way, if you only need the order of the normalizer (and not a description of the elements it contains), you should consider using the orbit-stabilizer theorem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetry group of a $p$-gon has order $2p$, so the subgroup generated by the given element has index 2 and is thus normal, ie the normalizer is the entire symmetry group.

Edit: As it was intended to be in the entire symmetric group $S_p$, we need a bit more.
First, we note that the normalizer consists of exactly those elements $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(12\dots p)\sigma^{-1}$ is some power of $(12\dots p)$. So we need to know how powers of $(12\dots p)$ look, and what we get if we conjugate $(12\dots p)$ by some permutation.The last question is easy, as we have $\sigma(12\dots p)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(1)\sigma(2)\dots\sigma(p))$. As for the powers of $(12\dots p)$, we can easily calculate that for $n < p$ we have $(12\dots p)^n = (1(1+n)(1+2n)\dots (1+pn))$ with all entries calculated mod $p$.
This means that if $\sigma$ nomalizes the given subgroup, then $\sigma$ has the form $\sigma(k) = ak + b\, (\textrm{mod}\ p)$ with $a\neq 0\, (\textrm{mod}\ p)$. Thus there are a total of $p(p-1)$ elements in the normalizer. (This is all assuming that $p$ is a prime by the way. If not, one needs to modify some of these things).

Edit: I got called away while writing the first edit, and it ended up being quite wrong actually. I have edited the last paragraph, and hopefully, it should now be correct.

Comment: Thanks, Tobias, I as confused, I thought $S_p$ was the symmetry group of a p-gon, when it is actually the group of permutations of p elements. Could you suggest what the m=normalizer is in that case?